# Group array of arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a query that produces this kind of result when converting to JSON. 
The result is from this query:

```
$query = "SELECT template_groups.id,template_groups.template_id , templates.color_ref
          FROM `template_groups`,`templates`
          where templates.template_id = template_groups.template_id  ";
```

Result:

```
array(135) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["template_groups"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["template_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
    ["templates"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["color_ref"]=>
      string(6) "F1F1F1"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["template_groups"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["template_id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    ["templates"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["color_ref"]=>
      string(6) "00326E"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["template_groups"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["template_id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
    ["templates"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["color_ref"]=>
      string(6) "191919"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to group the result so that for each `template_groups`, I have inside it all the `templates`. What could be the best solution in PHP?
The wanted result is an array of `template_groups`, each one has the corresponding array of `template_id` and its color.

Comment: this looks like `var_dump()` not `json_ecode()`

Comment: can you show what your desired output would look like?

Comment: yes it's a var_dump  to show me  the  structure 
and the  strcuture is array of template_groups inside them array  of template_id and color